# Entity Framework + Fluent Lightweight configuration for entity types only

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, fluent

I am trying to configure table names in model so that each table belongs to schema named by containing namespace with this code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (modelBuilder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));

    foreach (var creator in ModelCreators)
    {
        creator.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.ToTable(PrefixNamespace(c.ClrType)));
}

private string PrefixNamespace(Type type)
{
    var result = $"{type.Namespace.Split('.').Last()}.{type.Name}";
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that applying this configuration affects ComplexTypes as well, which are then configured as entities. How to apply this configuration to entities only? The `modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>(TEntity entity)` can configure only one entity at the time, but not all entity types are known during build time, some will be discovered from .dlls.

I was thinking about something like

```
modelBuilder.Types().Where(t => IsNotComplexType(t)).Configure(...)
```

but I don't know how to implement `IsNotComplexType` form available objects.

Answer (score 0):

I got to conclusion that complex types has to be set up explicitly via `DbModelBuilder.ComplexType<TComplexType>()`, so it won't be turned into entity after applying `ToTable(string tableName)` method.